# i want image instead of radiobuttons to be checked which is working fine in google chrome but not in internet explorer

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, internet-explorer

This is the code written in webform:

```
<asp:RadioButton CssClass="inline-rb" ID="RadioButton1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false" Text='&lt;img src=&#39;images/b3.jpg&#39;&gt;' GroupName="selection"    />  
<asp:RadioButton CssClass="inline-rb" ID="RadioButton1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false" Text='&lt;img src=&#39;images/b3.jpg&#39;&gt;' GroupName="selection"    />  
<asp:RadioButton CssClass="inline-rb" ID="RadioButton1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false" Text='&lt;img src=&#39;images/b3.jpg&#39;&gt;' GroupName="selection"    />
```

and css code is

```
.inline-rb input[type="radio"] {
    width: 200px;
    height:200px;
    display:none;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 1px;
    padding:4px 4px 4px 4px;

}

.inline-rb label {
    height:200px;
    width:200px;

    padding: 9px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    opacity: 0px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: /* opacity:0px;*/ thick groove #CCCCCC;
    padding:4px 4px 4px 4px;
}
.inline-rb input[type="radio"]:checked + label { 
    content: ' ';
    border: 5px dotted Red;

}
```

this is working fine in google chrome but not in internet explorer please give your suggestion.

Comment: what version of IE did you test it on?

Comment: IE version 11 , same code is working perfect on chrome